# conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch

Tags: puppet

I've installed the CentOS VM machine from PuppetLearning and followed the tutorial.
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/

now, I get this error when i try to install the Puppet Hiera:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/installing.html

```
> lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: CentOS
Release:    5.7
Codename:   Final

# enable the Puppet Labs package repos: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html
> rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/5/products/i386/puppetlabs-release-5-7.noarch.rpm

> puppet resource package hiera ensure=installed
Notice: /Package[hiera]/ensure: created
package { 'hiera':
  ensure => '1.2.1-1.el5',
}

> puppet resource package hiera-puppet ensure=installed

Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hiera-puppet' returned 1: 

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/extlookup2hiera conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/backend/puppet_backend.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/scope.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera_puppet.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_array.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_hash.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_include.rb conflicts between attempted installs of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el5.noarch and puppet-3.3.0-1.el5.noarch
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Puppet-hiera installation page:

**Note:** Puppet 3 does not need the hiera-puppet package, and may refuse to install if it is present. You can safely remove hiera-puppet in the process of upgrading to Puppet 3.

Ref: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/installing.html